# How to suppress Python from showing status of my random forest run?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, ensemble-modeling

How can I stop scikit-learn Random Forest from displaying the following status output during run? I have already set verbosity to -1 in RandomForestClassifier() and GridSearchCV()

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.3s remaining:    1.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.4s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done   2 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.3s remaining:    1.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.4s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done   2 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.0s finished
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend ThreadingBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   2 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.5s remaining:    2.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   9 out of   9 | elapsed:    0.8s finished
```

Comment: as it seems you should look into verbosity option (if exists) in module for parallel tasks

Comment: You need to show the model‘s code